# getting ListView image in next Activity by url

Tags: android, listview

I am having `ListView` items in `BaseAdapter` class.If I click the image means it should be shown in another `Activity`. Here all images are loaded by url.

This is my intent class

```
    final FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

    feedImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i1=new Intent(activity,Second.class);
        String image_url="http://api.ryhill.in/getHotels/1";
         i1.putExtra("image_url", image_url);
        //feedImageView.setImageResource(feedItems.get(position).getPath());
         activity.startActivity(i1);



        }
    });
```

Second activity

```
     public class Second extends Activity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String id = i.getExtras().getString("image_url");
}

}
```

pls suggest solution for this

Comment: what is your problem actually ?

Comment: I have to pass the image to next activity.but image is not loaded in second activity

Comment: your this code working or not?

Comment: Can you please post your whole activity and adapter class

Comment: You are passing wrong URL, You need pass image_path/Image_url. But you are passing your API url. First parse your webservice response, and then work further

Comment: I'm getting some text values through intent.But i can't able to get the listview image.

Answer (score 0):

Use it, you will get the image URl in your `Second` Activity:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about [caching the images](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html), also if you download them did you give a look to [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) from google devs ?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this-

```
   Intent i = getIntent();
    String id = i.getStringExtra("image_url");
```

Comment: are you able to go to next class?

Comment: yes.its going to second activity while clicking image

Answer (score -1):

Have you maybe considered trying to use `Getter / Setter` methods as an alternative to `putExtras()` ?

You could set your URL inside a `static String`, and use `getter` in your second activity, to get the `String` from your intent activity.

I think it should work for your solution, although maybe nto the smoothest one.